# Regular expression to match handlebar expression and default value

Tags: regex

I'm loosely following a handlebar pattern to replace instances of a `{{copy}}` expression inside a string.

Here are some example of strings/scenarios I'm trying to match:

- `{{copy}}`
- `some text, then {{copy}}, then some other other text`
- `some {{copy 'default value here'}} here`

Essentially `{{copy}}` can occur anywhere within a string, and can also include a default value which I also need to pluck out using regex.

I've tried the following which I thought would match, but am having no luck.

```
    \b{{copy*}}\b
```

Comment: Do not use word boundaries if the `{{` and `}}` do not need to be preceded/followed with word chars. Just use `{{copy[^}]*}}`

Comment: Note that `copy*` matches either `cop` or `copy` and also `copyyyyy` You could also use for example `{{copy\b.*?}}`

Comment: `{{(copy\b)(.*?)}}` would place things into capture groups 1 and 2 respectively. https://regex101.com/r/n2G2TH/1/

Comment: Craig, what is your intention? Please clarify, or let know what works for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Your suggestion worked perfectly thank you.

Comment: And I was able to capture the default value with @MonkeyZeus suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
{{copy\s*([^}]*)}}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PQ7KAs/1). Details:

- `{{copy` - a literal text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^}]*)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than `}`
- `}}` - a `}}` string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/{{(copy)\b(?: +'([^']*)')?}}/
```

Explanation:

- `{{` - expect handlebar start
- `(copy)` - capture text `copy` (replace with `[a-z]+` to support variable keywords)
- `\b` - expect a word boundary
- `(?:` ... `)?` - non-capturing group, the trailing `?` makes it optional

  - `+'([^']*)'` - expect 1+ spaces, a quote, capture everything after until before next quote, expect quote
- `}}` - expect handlebar end
- now you can reference the capture groups with `$1` and `$2`, or `\1` and `\2`, or array depending on the regex engine/language construct.